# custom parameter when launching android test from command line

Tags: java, android, variables, command-line-arguments, robotium

I can launch my Android applications Junit/Robotium tests from the command line like this:

```
adb shell am instrument -w com.myapp.client.test/android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner
```

However, I want to somehow include a custom parameter that allows me specify whether the test is to be run in "Portrait" mode or "landscape" mode.

How can I:

1. specify that custom parameter in the command-line command?
2. How can I access that custom parameter's value in the Java code?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You can specify a custom parameter using

```
adb shell am insrument -e <NAME> <VALUE> <package/runner>
```

You can reach it's value using the bundle that is available if you override the `onCreate` method of the `InstrumentationTestRunner`.

E.g:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

 value = (String) savedInstanceState.get("name");

}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can extend Android Instrumentation runner and *override* **oncreate()** method to get custom parameter from command line. Use your customized instrumentation runner while executing test cases.

```
public class CustomInstrumentationRunner extends android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner{

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle arguments) {
    //process you parameters here.     
super.onCreate(arguments);
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    try {
       logger = CustomLogger.GetLogger();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
    super.onStart();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I made a hack solution to this.  It doesn't look like there is a clean solution here.

My hack is to utilize the "small", "medium", and "large" attributes that you can attach to tests.

```
   @MediumTest
    public void testPortraitTest1() throws Exception{
        this.MetaDataTest(Solo.PORTRAIT);        
    }

    @LargeTest
    public void testLanscapeTest1() throws Exception{
        this.MetaDataTest(Solo.LANDSCAPE);        
    }
```

then you can use your batch file to call the medium tests first and then the large tests, like this:

```
adb shell am instrument -w -e size medium com.me.client.test/android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner 
adb shell am instrument -w -e size large com.me.client.test/android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner
```

shame on google for not making this easier.

Answer (score 0):

The way I did this is:

Before I run the test, I save a text file in the sdcard\

When the test starts, in the setUp, I parse each line of the text file and extract the key/value

arg1=valueX
arg2=valueY